# Get the positions of multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, position, draggable, each

I am trying to get the individual positions of multiple draggable elements using jQuerys .position and .each functions.

This is what i have so far...

**JS**

```
function newAppDraggable() {
    $('.App').draggable({
        containment: "#AppBox",
        grid: [ 60, 60 ],
        stack: ".App"
    });
};

$(function() {
    $('.AppList').droppable({
        accept: ".App",
        tolerance: 'fit',
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            $(".App").each(function( index ) {
            var position = $(this).position();
            var posTop = position.top;
            var posLeft = position.left;
            $( "#posThis" ).html(index+":"+posTop+":"+posLeft);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="AppList">
    <div id="TimenDate" class="App Fixed Size110x350">
    </div>

    <div id="User" class="App Fixed Size110x290">
    <p id="posThis"></p>
    </div>

    <div id="Weather" class="App Fixed Size110x350">
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/strydom/nAAS7/2/embedded/result/) for better explanation. On the fiddle the index stays at 2 and the positions only change when the 3rd app is moved.

what I would like is to be able to get the positions of all the individual apps and possibly save them in an array in a cookie (or something of the sort) so that i can reload them in their last positions when the page is refreshed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In vanilla javascript and on modern browsers that support [element.getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.getBoundingClientRect)

Both of the following examples have been modified to demonstrate how the attained positions of each element can be added to an array that can then be accessed later.

You could get the position information with this technique.

```
var apps = document.querySelectorAll(".App"),
    positions = [];

Array.prototype.forEach.call(apps, function (app, index) {
    var positionInfo = app.getBoundingClientRect();

    positions.push(positionInfo);
    console.log(index + ":" + positionInfo.top + ":" + positionInfo.left);
});

console.log(positions);
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/LxqzC/)

In the above example the browser must also have support for [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll)

Using jquery, it would be something like this, using [jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), [jQuery.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) and [jQuery.position](http://api.jquery.com/position/)

```
var apps = $(".App"),
    positions = [];

$.each(apps, function (index, app) {
    var positionInfo = $(app).position();

    positions.push(positionInfo);
    console.log(index + ":" + positionInfo.top + ":" + positionInfo.left);
});

console.log(positions);
```

on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/4nv62/)

Comment: So this does not work on jQuery? All of my script is in jQuery Plus all of the plugins i use. I don't think i could afford to change everything now. Thanks for the input though

Comment: Why would you need to change from jquery (jquery is a javascript library, a collection of routines written in javascript for user use in javascript)?

Comment: oh sorry i misunderstood what you meant by vanilla script. so how would i implement this with my existing code?

Comment: Never mind i see you have added the jquery code :) I have changed your script to put the position in the <p> tag and i get the same result. its only getting the position for the 3rd app http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/4nv62/

Comment: now you have changed it back to .App i am getting the same result that i had before with the index being 2 and the position being that of the 3rd app http://jsfiddle.net/strydom/4nv62/5/

Comment: But you loop though the nodes, and each time you put the value into the same element ("User"). Therefore the value displayed in element "User", will be the last value obtained (that of element "weather").

Comment: okay i can understand that.. But how do i get the values for all of them? or pick out which values i want? they should be (1:0:0) (2:0:360) (3:0:660) but i don't know how to choose specific ones. I have also updated the bottom of my question to try explain what i want to do with the positions.

Comment: Addition: if it gets the value of the last element surly the index should be 3 not 2?

Comment: Thank you very much! i am a complete novice as you can probably tell. One more thing, you said that the new code puts the positions in an array that can be used later. How can i get the information out of this array? say for index 0 ...

Comment: Please don't forget to accept this as the answer to your question if you feel it deserves it.

Comment: I guess it does but i am still stuck on how to actually access the individual positions. should i open another question for that?

Comment: I have given you all the information, so yes, you should create a question, along with examples of what you have tried, that is specific to your problem and accessing array elements.